# Connecting nodes with the text marked by tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I'm editing a text where I need to mark words (or short sentences i.e. not multiple lines of text) by encircling them in boxes and connect those boxes with the text I will add on later. `tikzmark` seems to be the best choice to  mark the words because I will mark arbitrary number of words in a given page. The tikz `node` seems best suited to add and connect text to those `tikzmark`ed text because I'd like to add my own text in whatever position I see fit in the page.

I find it difficult to connect the nodes and position them relative to the text marked by `tikzmark`. Here is a demo depicting what I'd like to do:

[image]

Here is the code I've written.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{blindtext} % not useful
\usepackage{lipsum} % not intuitive
\begin{document}


% \lipsum[5] % here I wanted to limit the lipsum text to 5 lines but couldn't manage to do it. So I commented it out.

Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla

IBM's main headquarters is located in \tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt, draw]{falseword1}{Antarctica} IBM sold its personal computer division to \tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt, draw]{falseword2}{Apple} in the year of 2005. Lenovo has since kept the design philosophy of IBM quite well. For instance the Lenovo's X1 series  Laptops are so aesthetic and durable as the IBM's X40 series.
\tikz\node[below of=falseword1](correctword1){New York};
\tikz\node[below of=falseword2](correctword2){Lenovo Group};

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[latex-latex] (falseword1) -- (correctword1);}

Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The creation of your `tikzmarknode`s is correct, but the drawing part is not. In a new `tikzpicture` with options `remember picture, overlay`, use ordinary Ti*k*Z commands—in this case `\draw`.

I suggest you place all these notes in the margins and reference absolute locations since you may change the text in the paragraph later and you don't want to reposition each time. For example, perhaps the paragraph above `Antarctica` gets extended by a few words later and there is no longer room for your note.

I used the package `tikzpagenodes`, which provides the node `(current page text area)`, so I can draw to the text edge and then a bit beyond. (I used 1.5 cm in the code below.) Changing the `shift` values will adjust the positioning of your note.

Remember you must compile twice when using `tikzmark`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\begin{document}

Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla

IBM's main headquarters is located in \tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt, draw]{falseword1}{Antarctica} IBM sold its personal computer division to \tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt, draw]{falseword2}{Apple} in the year of 2005. Lenovo has since kept the design philosophy of IBM quite well. For instance the Lenovo's X1 series  Laptops are so aesthetic and durable as the IBM's X40 series.

Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue, thick, ->](falseword1.north east)-|([shift={(1.5,-.8)}]current page text area.east|-falseword1.north east)node[below]{New York};
\draw[blue, thick, ->](falseword2.north west)-|([shift={(-1.5,-.8)}]current page text area.west|-falseword2.north west)node[below]{Lenovo Group};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```